# How to add dart run time command arguments to Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart

When I am running a flutter app I need to add this argument. Otherwise, the app is not working.

`--no-sound-null-safety`

Example:

```
flutter build apk --no-sound-null-safety
```

or

```
flutter run --no-sound-null-safety
```

It's easy to add on android studio. (Edit configurations..). But, I didn't know how to add this kind of argument on Xcode?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

add `EXTRA_FRONT_END_OPTIONS` in `User-Defined` in `Build Settings`. value is `--no-sound-null-safety`

Comment: It doesn't work unfortunately on CI/CD (bitrise)

Comment: you have add that value on bitrise.

Answer (score 0):

just keep running  code in  vs or android studio then open in xcode it will not throw null safety issue for any deprecated package